# Doctrine cache using APC in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to use the doctrine cache in order to save the data results from queries.

I've updated the doctrine info in the config file with the following cache config options:

```
orm:
    ...
    metadata_cache_driver: apc
    query_cache_driver: apc
    result_cache_driver: apc
```

Here is a query example where I apply the results cache:

```
    $query = $this->repository->createQueryBuilder('fp')
        ->where('fp.userId = :userId')
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'favorite');

    return $query->getResult();
```

It retrieves the data without error but it seems that it doesn't store the result in the APC cache.

I try the following code in order to check if the query result has been cached in APC:

```
    $q = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache();
    $data = $q->fetch('favorite');
```

However `data` always returns the `false` boolean.

I've checked that APC is enabled in the php.ini files and also it appears enabled in the Symfony profiler.

Anything I might be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration seems fine and result is most probably stored in `APC` cache.

Method `useResultCache` works in a way that `Doctrine` performs query and stores result in cache when query is run for the first time. After that (within `timeout` set) database is not queried for result, it is fetched from cache directly.

I think that a real issue here is the way you verify if result is stored in `APC` cache or not. I would suggest other (more reliable) ways to check it:

1. See log file and check queries which are run during request. You should see sql only for first request (when cache is not populated)
2. Try to change a value in database after first query run. You should see the same result (despite your edit) when query is run for the second time.

Also make sure for which environment (`dev`, `prod`) your caching driver (`APC`) is configured as this might differ between various environments (cache is often disabled in `dev` environment)

**EDIT**: I did some further research and now I'm sure that your verification method is wrong. Method `fetch` you are using looks like:

```
public function fetch($id)
{
    return $this->doFetch($this->getNamespacedId($id));
}
```

so fact that you are using `favorite` key in your `useResultCache` method doesn't mean that `doctrine` uses this key internally as it is transformed by `getNamespacedId` method.

Check [fetch method](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php#L76) and [getNamespacedId method](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php#L162)